# Export DNNLinearCombinedClassifier with multiple serving functions

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I am training a [DNNLinearCombinedClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNLinearCombinedClassifier) and serving it for low latency predictions through [tensorflow-serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving). The current serving signature expects a serialized tf.example.

I want to be able to export the same model with multiple serving_fn, since I want to change the expected data format.

I cannot use the [ServingInputReceiver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/export/ServingInputReceiver) `receiver_tensors_alternatives` because I need to apply slightly different transformation to my features depending on the provided data format. These transformations are mostly reshaping my features.

Is there any way to export a model providing multiple different `ServingInputReceiver`s?

Comment: Why not use ```tf.keras``` and ```tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing```

Comment: Hello. Can you expand a little bit on how `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing` can be used here?

Comment: You don't have to create an input function for serving if you use that .

Comment: You can use ```tf.keras.Input``` + ```tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing``` to replace ```input_fn``` .

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want two different signatures for the same model, and you want to apply different transformations for the input for each signature, correct?  You could do this in the serving code, but you want to make sure that you apply the same transforms during training, and trying to duplicate the code in two places opens the door for training/serving skew.

One option is to branch your TFX pipeline, so that you have two Transforms feeding two Trainers, with different transformations being prepended to your models.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to give a bit more context on my issue, we are trying to export a `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` that would work both with tf.examples and ExampleListWithContext. [tensorflow-ranking](https://github.com/tensorflow/ranking) provides some functions to create a serving signature that expects `ExampleListWithContext`, but the parsed feature tensors are not shaped in a way that would work with a `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`. This is why we need to transform them (mostly reshaping) to feed them to the `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`. T